# Script to Organize long email chains into "boxes"

Tags: email, parsing, outlook

I do Research and Development tax credits, and I get the majority of "evidence" as emails. They are given to me as a ZIP, some of them are 30 back and forths between dev's, screenshots keywords etc... In order for me to do my work, I usually break them down into the key "obstacles" and the correlate all the emails relating to engaging these obstacles (basically the debugging), into a big mind map.

Recently I was given about 2000 email messages, all in the .msg format, and well I have about 3 weeks to write out my report, and to do it effectively I need to write out the experimentation in chronological format, basically the entire process relating to overcoming said obstacle from start to finish.

I estimate it taking me about 100+ hours to do so manually, (manually snipping and attaching keywords/ date's to each email msg), I was wondering if there is a algorithmic way of doing it, there are about 200 email .msg's, all with 5-20 emails in them.

If there is a way I can do this in less then 100 hours with nearly 10 years of more public relations type work (I have a computer science degree, but I am a technical writer for RnD), and little if any recent programming experience.

Comment: Doesn't look like something one can easily automate unless I am missing what it is exactly you are trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly how you want to filter emails and attachments in the store... But the Outlook object model provides a rich programming model which you can use to get the job done. For example, you can write a VBA macro or develop an Outlook add-in. The latter allows installing your solution on other PCs. So, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

Also you may find the [Selecting an API or technology for developing solutions for Outlook 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900714.aspx) article helpful.

Comment: I realize I didn't thank you for this, sending me on the right search path, I found a good macro and it worked, took some digging and some modifying to get it to do what I wanted (organize by date, separate the chain emails) believe I also used a searching tool from sourceforge which also greatly helped after it was all cleaned up. Sorry bout the late thanks, but it was a hectic week!